# typescript runs strange on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, typescript

I have a typescript project and want my running code to get generated by heroku when I deploy. I therefore added `"postinstall": "tsc"` to `package.json` so that `tsc` would be run on heroku after `npm install` is complete (I do have typescript in my dependencies).

It does run, but for some reason, tsc crashes with `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` on an obscure file `.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map-ordered.js` which it shouldn't be running on at all. This setup works perfectly on my machine, on Circle.ci, and on a freshly cloned repo.

I had a theory that maybe tsc was being run in the wrong directory, but when I used `pwd && ls && tsc` It printed the correct directory (`/tmp/build_5292b1b9c3c13c35489f46510acb565e`) and the files that are in my directory.

My question is: Why is `tsc` running in this strange way on heroku, and what do I have to do to make typescript work on a heroku deployment?

Comment: It sounds like the code you have running on Heroku isn't what you're testing against. Try running `heroku releases` and compare the git hash with the latest git hash you have locally.

Comment: I'm using CircleCI to automatically deploy once tests pass, it would be really weird if the repo was somehow altered on its way. I don't think that's the problem.